# Dilemma between keeping my code with pure js + jQuery AJAX calls or getting rid of every client script and rewriting the code in .NET only

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, security

I've developed a website (jQuery + .NET/C#) and it's 90% ready. Before a publish it I decided to face the truth and I admitted to myself the code isn't totally hack-safe. To be honest it's barely hack-safe. It's because I've been practicing some bad web programming habits (like relying too much on client scripting instead shelling it into server-side).

To be more precise, I've being using too much jQuery I guess and now I see all my webmethods are exposed in .js files. I've minified and obfuscated but it doesn't prevent a determined cheater to get all my stuff. That's one point.

Other issue is the fact I have some webmethods that return a lot of data from my database. Not confidential data, but some nice data my system generates and I don't wanna any external website to call it and display it like it is their material.

One of solutions I thought about was to generate all html in server-side and return it to .js and then append it to his respective element (in this way I'd hide all the intelligence beyond it) but it doesn't solve all the problems I related above.

So my question is... do you guys think it's safer to rewrite everything using ASP.NET controls or is there any way to make it **REAL SAFE** using the code I have (like avoiding external callings to my webmethods)?

I know without looking to the code it's hard to make an opinion but it's huge! And it's all about what I said (too much client-scripting, little server-side).

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want a totally hack-safe Site, then you will be disappointed. you can just make it the hardest possible.

This is easiest with sites processed server-sided, and then served to the client. but i would also recommend not moving all to the server, because after all the server will have to process each and every request you make to it.

I have experienced, that it is the "easiest" to make all data-serving and evaluation logic serversided and rendering, as well as easy processing logic client-sided. Thus combining the strong sides of both technologies at minimal security risk. e.g. after an AJAX-Call to serve some data (if you even want to do that) you can call render, update and processing logic client sided with the help of `success:` or `failure:`, as well as `after:` or similar keywords.

Try some new things out. if you move it all to one technology/process you will have to take the disadvantages of this process. split things up!

Comment: Yeah, I first used ajax to enhance page processing speed and it worked greatly, but it became an addiction and now I overuse jQuery + ajax. I'll probably push the most part of the project to server-side I guess. Since my site it's all about championships, ranking and other contests stuff I can't compromise any sort of hacking at all. At least I have to make it at minimum risk possible. Thanks for the advices.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you can check on serverside, which domain is calling your backend -> deny for unallowed domains. ([Check this ticket](http://classicasp.aspfaq.com/general/how-do-i-protect-my-client-side-javascript-code.html))

To reduce javascript magic, you can move the logic into backend as you said.

Maybe some tricks to save your javascript code ( [Check this out](http://classicasp.aspfaq.com/general/how-do-i-protect-my-client-side-javascript-code.html) )

Comment: Is it possible to do such thing (domain checking) inside a WebMethod, since it's static? After reading your reference, I'm even more inclined to change (almost) everything to server side. Thanks for the tips.